# Rebuild Typescript file with pm2 watch

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, pm2, nodemon

I've added `pm2` to one of the repos I work with because I want to restart the local server on crashes and such. App engine handles that for us in production (hopefully ). It's an amazing service really, and I was hoping to replace `nodemon` with it, but I can't get it to automate the Typescript build on restart.

I was messing around with scripts, and configs, with no luck. I basically need it to to run `/node_modules/.bin/tsc` to rebuild the `dist` folder on save. Otherwise, I end up with a stale file that's reloaded for no reason other than change detection.

I haven't found anything online, maybe I'm not looking hard enough, and I don't want to run `ts-node` as an alternative. I tried running `nodemon` before and after, with no avail.

**Some files:**

`ecosystem.config.js`

```
  apps: [
    {
      name: "example",
      script: ".",
      exp_backoff_restart_delay: 1000,
      watch_option: {
        persistent: true,
        ignoreInitial: true,
      }
};
```

`package.json`

```
"pm2-start": "pm2 start && pm2 logs",
```

I tried adding the `npm run build` before `pm2 start` and it worked the first time, but not on reloads.

Thanks in advance.